# Perl to group columns in csv with multilines

Tags: perl, csv, hash

I have a csv (separated by ,) with multilines. The csv has 4 columns, of which first 3 columns contain multiline text while the group by happens on last column.

**Input csv content**: /tmp/test.tmp.csv

```
"Total Sections",ota,4!n,01
"Input History",80,"HHMM28!c1!a[4!a]
6X
9X]",1
"T (MR)",17t,(MTR),02
"Input History",80,"HHMM28!c1!a[4!a]
6X
9X]",2
Reference,:4!t/1c,:(Text1)/(Text2),30
Reference,:4!t/1c,:(Text1)/(Text2),32
```

Above csv consists of 6 records, record 2 and 4 are with multilines.

**Expected output** (group by separate is space):

```
"Total Sections",ota,4!n,01
"Input History",80,"HHMM28!c1!a[4!a]
6X
9X]",1 2
"T (MR)",17t,(MTR),02
Reference,:4!t/1c,:(Text1)/(Text2),30 32
```

My **perl script** (read first 3 fields in hash as key, the last field in hash as value, print to csv with join):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my %hash;
my @array;
my $in_qfn = "/tmp/test.tmp.csv";
my $out_qfn = "/tmp/test.out.tmp.csv";

# Li: Parsing multilines in csv
my $parser = Text::CSV->new({
   binary => 1,
   auto_diag => 1,
   sep_char => ','
});

# Li: output multilines to csv
my $csvo = Text::CSV->new({
   binary => 1,
   eol => "\r\n",
   sep_char => ','
});

open(my $data, '<:encoding(utf8)', $in_qfn) or die "Could not open $in_qfn: $!\n";
open(my $sts, '>:encoding(utf8)', $out_qfn) or die "Could not write $out_qfn: $!\n";

while (my $fields = $parser -> getline($data)) {
   my $fz = $fields->[0];
   my $fo = $fields->[1];
   my $ft = $fields->[2];
   my $fth = $fields->[3];
   my @flds = ($fz, $fo, $ft, $fth);

   # Li: push the first 3 columns as key and the last column as value
   push(@{$hash{@flds[0..2]} }, $flds[3]);
}

# Li: print to output csv without join yet
for my $k (sort keys %hash) {
   my @fldsAll = ($k, @{ $hash{$k}});
   print("###LI### 1: key: $k, value: @fldsAll\n");
   $csvo -> print($sts, \@fldsAll);
}
```

However, the script doesn't work perfectly, the hash key got lost due to the multiline and possibly special characters and without double quote everywhere.

**Defected output**:

```
(MTR),02
4!n,01
:(Text1)/(Text2),30,32
"HHMM28!c1!a[4!a]
6X
9X]",1,2
```

Any idea on how to fix it? Or a brand new perl solution is also appreciate.

Comment: Are you expecting the hash key to be an array? You're just using the last member of the array currently.

Comment: Yes I do expect to use the array slice: @flds[0..2] as the hash key. Is it not correct? I also tried to assign @fldsSlc=@flds[0..2], and assign the array @fldsSlc as hash key, same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an array as a hash key like you've done because rather than use all the values, it only uses the last one.

And you can't use a reference to the array as the keys aren't related to the values in the array. Take this example code...

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
  {
  my @a=(1,2,3);
  $hash{\@a}=10;
  }
```

Because the scope of `@a` is local to the loop, you end up with 3 keys. If you put the `my @a;` outside of the loop, you end up with 1 key. You can change the contents of the array and it would have no effect on the key.

Instead what you'll have to do is `join` the array into one string.

```
push(@{$hash{join("\t",@flds[0..2])} }, $flds[3]);
```

I've used a tab, but any string of characters that won't ever appear in any of the 3 columns is what you want, so that if required you can `split` it later to get the original values back.